# What does anonymous refer to in forums?

Tags: user-accounts, forum

I reading a topic from one of the programming forum, and I saw this in the bottom of the forum page.

> 5 User(s) are reading this topic 2 members, 3 guests, 0 anonymous
>
> users abc,john joe

I know the two members refer to abc and john joe, three guests probably refer to non-member, but how about  anonymous?

Comment: It may refer to people who have not logged into the site, so their identity is unknown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, for some forums or communities, the users open and view some posts, but they don't want to let others to know that they have viewed the post.

In addition, it looks like `don't show the user name` and `hide my user name`. Or it could be a settings for the user profile. Such `don't let others know what/where I have gone or viewed`.